# Outer Join - Not Working, wont show null rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that does a couple of things. First it is supposed to get all the teams with the divisionid of 1. Then it is supposed to get the number of wins registered in the results column.

It accomplishes this, however if the team has no data registered in the results table it will not show TeamName 0(wins). Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Table 1: Active Teams

```
 aid teamid divisionid
  1    1        1
  2    2        1
  3    3        1
  4    4        2
```

Table 2: Teams

```
  teamid teamname 
    1     Argos
    2     Leafs 
    3     Blue Jays
    4     Ducks
```

Table 3: Results
  rid teamid result
   1    1     'w'
   2    2     'l'

End Result Goal

```
 divid teamname  wins
   1     Argos    1
   1     Leafs    0
   1     Bluejays 0
```

Current Query

```
SELECT activeteams.divisionid, teams.teamname, res.wins
FROM activeteams
JOIN teams ON activeteams.teamid = teams.teamid
  OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN result =  'w' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0) AS wins, 
      results.teamid AS teamid
  FROM results
  GROUP BY results.teamid
  )res ON teams.teamid = res.teamid
WHERE activeteams.divisionid = 1
```

Comment: I would use a left join in this instance, not an outer join

Comment: could you make a sqlfiddle of this?

Comment: I had a silly error when i tried left join, left join worked! I was just about to post a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT activeteams.divisionid, teams.teamname, res.wins
FROM activeteams
INNER JOIN teams ON activeteams.teamid = teams.teamid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN result =  'w' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0) AS wins, 
        teamid
    FROM results
    GROUP BY teamid
  ) res ON teams.teamid = res.teamid
WHERE activeteams.divisionid = 1
```